# Perl split stops at first line

Tags: perl, file, split

EDIT : rewrite the example to make it more clear

i'm having data into a file named *RTR-shpolicymap_751257S0_126.xxx.xxx.xxx_OUTPUT* :

```
751257S0;126.xxx;FastEthernet0;up;up;not set;not set;;
751257S0;126.xxx;BRI0;down;down;not set;not set;;
751257S0;126.xxx;BRI0:1;down;down;not set;not set;;
751257S0;126.xxx;BRI0:2;down;down;not set;not set;;
751257S0;126.xxx;ATM0;up;up;not set;not set;;
751257S0;126.xxx;ATM0.835;up;up;not set;not set;;
```

A perl script execute a SSH connection to the router, and when the connection is established, it calls the function *executeCommands*
This function is described here :

```
sub executeCommands {
    open(SSHCONFIG, "/tech/restools/scripts/mynet/RTR-ssh.conf");
    while (<SSHCONFIG>) {
        @ligne = split(/;/, $_ );
        $listop = $ligne[0];
        $listcmd = $ligne[1];
        $fileprefix = $ligne[2];
        $parsername = $ligne[3];
        $parsername =~ s/\s+\z// ;
        @cmd = split(/,/, $listcmd);

        #Si l'operateur passe en parametre match l'operateur dans le fichier de config - execution des commandes
        if ($listop =~ /$operateur/) {
            for ($index = 0; $index <= $#cmd; $index++) {
                $command = $cmd[$index];
                &changeCommand(\$command);
                &sendCommand($command, $fileprefix);
            }
        }
        else {
            next;
        }
```

The config file contains this :

```
OBS,9 Cegetel,Altitude;sh policy-map $policyinterface;RTR-shpolicymap;RTR-parser9.pl
```

Now, i'm having troubles with the function *changeCommand*

```
sub changeCommand {
    my $arg1 = $_[0];
    if ($$arg1=~/^(.*)(\$policyinterface)(.*)/) {
        print "recherche de l'interface contenant la policy voice correspondante... \n" ;
        $fichier_parser1OUTPUT = `find $WORKINGDIR -type f -name RTR-shipint_\"*$codesite*$ip*OUTPUT\"` ;
        @table_fichier_parser1OUTPUT = split(/\n/,$fichier_parser1OUTPUT);
        for ($index4 = 0 ; $index4 <= $#table_fichier_parser1OUTPUT ; $index4++) {
            $fichierNeeded = $table_fichier_parser1OUTPUT[$index4];
            open(DATA,$fichierNeeded) || die ("Erreur d'ouverture de $fichierNeeded\n");
            print "file $fichierNeeded have been opened \n";
            while (my $lineData=<DATA>) {
                print "i am printing this line $lineData \n";
                my @lineSplitter = split(/;/, $lineData );
                print "3e arg est <<$lineSplitter[2]>>\n";
            }
        $command = "sh policy-map int " . $interfaceNeeded ;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is there, this is what happens when i'm executing my script :

```
recherche de l'interface contenant la policy voice correspondante...
file /tech/restools/tmp/mynet/RTR-working-dir/RTR-shipint_751257S0_126.108.2.250_OUTPUT have been opened
i am printing this line 751257S0;126.108.2.250;FastEthernet0;up;up;not set;not set;;
3e arg est <<FastEthernet0>>
```

Where is my error ? Is it because i'm already using *$_* in a previous function ?

Testing a similar script alone is working...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict ;

my $codesite="751257S0" ;
my $ip = "126.xxx.xxx.xxx" ;
my $WORKINGDIR="/tech/restools/tmp/mynet/RTR-working-dir";

my $fichier_parser1OUTPUT = `find $WORKINGDIR -type f -name RTR-shipint_\"*$codesite*$ip*OUTPUT\"` ;
my @table_fichier_parser1OUTPUT = split(/\n/,$fichier_parser1OUTPUT);
for (my $index4 = 0 ; $index4 <= $#table_fichier_parser1OUTPUT ; $index4++) {
        my $fichierNeeded = $table_fichier_parser1OUTPUT[$index4];
        open(DATA,$fichierNeeded) || die ("Erreur d'ouverture de $fichierNeeded\n");
        print "file $fichierNeeded have been opened \n";
        while (my $lineData=<DATA>) {
                print "i am printing this line $lineData \n";
                my @lineSplitter = split(/;/, $lineData );
                print "3e arg est <<$lineSplitter[2]>>\n";
                }
        }
```

prints

```
i am printing this line 751257S0;126.108.2.250;FastEthernet0;up;up;not set;not set;;

3e arg est <<FastEthernet0>>
i am printing this line 751257S0;126.108.2.250;BRI0;down;down;not set;not set;;

3e arg est <<BRI0>>
i am printing this line 751257S0;126.108.2.250;BRI0:1;down;down;not set;not set;;

3e arg est <<BRI0:1>>
...
```

Comment: Yes, adding print scalar shows "1"

Comment: Any chance the file has windows line endings?

Comment: The `split` would still yield several lines because Windows has `\n` in its line ending.

Comment: Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea.  The first three lines are extraneous to your question; you need to set the file name, then open it and use it.  Did you print `$_` before the `split`?  Do you have `$/` set to an odd value earlier in your script, or is it undefined (via `local $/;`) so that the whole file is slurped?  Did you print all the split fields?  These are basic debugging techniques.

Comment: @AKHolland: Windows line endings still contain newlines, so the lines are separated properly. The problem comes with `chomp` which removes the trailing newline but leaves the CR in place.

Comment: @GuiO: There is nothing in your code that would cause what you describe. Where did your file come from? Where did your file come from? You should debug by adding `print ">>>> $_"` right after the `while` statement and before the `split`. That way you will be able to see what is being read from the file.

Comment: @GuiO: I assume you expect `find` to return just one file?

Answer (score 1):

Given the data from the question in a file `fichier.1`, the following code can produce what appears to be the effect you're seeing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/;
my $fichierNeeded = "fichier.1";
open(DATA,$fichierNeeded) || die ("Erreur d'ouverture de $fichierNeeded\n");
print "Fichier $fichierNeeded est ouvert\n";
while (<DATA>) {
    print "Ligne: $_";
    my @lineSplitter = split(/;/, $_ );
    print "3rd arg is <<$lineSplitter[2]>>\n";
}
```

The output from this is:

```
Fichier fichier.1 est ouvert
Ligne: 751257S0;126.xxx;FastEthernet0;up;up;not set;not set;;
751257S0;126.xxx;BRI0;down;down;not set;not set;;
751257S0;126.xxx;BRI0:1;down;down;not set;not set;;
751257S0;126.xxx;BRI0:2;down;down;not set;not set;;
751257S0;126.xxx;ATM0;up;up;not set;not set;;
751257S0;126.xxx;ATM0.835;up;up;not set;not set;;
3rd arg is <<FastEthernet0>>
```

If you omit the `local $/;`, the output is:

```
Fichier fichier.1 est ouvert
Ligne: 751257S0;126.xxx;FastEthernet0;up;up;not set;not set;;
3rd arg is <<FastEthernet0>>
Ligne: 751257S0;126.xxx;BRI0;down;down;not set;not set;;
3rd arg is <<BRI0>>
Ligne: 751257S0;126.xxx;BRI0:1;down;down;not set;not set;;
3rd arg is <<BRI0:1>>
Ligne: 751257S0;126.xxx;BRI0:2;down;down;not set;not set;;
3rd arg is <<BRI0:2>>
Ligne: 751257S0;126.xxx;ATM0;up;up;not set;not set;;
3rd arg is <<ATM0>>
Ligne: 751257S0;126.xxx;ATM0.835;up;up;not set;not set;;
3rd arg is <<ATM0.835>>
```

Since you've not given us a usable fragment of code (the loop is incomplete, even), and your code unnecessarily makes us run a `find` command on a directory etc, we cannot reproduce your environment sufficiently well.

As I noted in a comment, you need to learn how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  These are two names for (and two descriptions of) the same basic idea.  The code I provide is close to being an MCVE or SSCCE (except it is not clear that it reproduces your problem).

Note also a couple of basic debugging techniques.  Printing out the data you just read is the most elementary way of spotting problems.  In the first sample output, the whole file was slurped into memory at once.  If the setting of `$/` is hidden from your code (someone is careless in a subroutine you call), this can be invaluable.  I also delimit the matched field (enclosing them in doubled angle brackets) so that I can see more easily if there are weird characters in the data.  If you're not sure what's happening, the first thing you should do is add some print statements to print what you're working on.

Comment: This code is part of a very big script, bash calling perl with args, trying to connect to equipments by SSH, writing down to file commands like "sh ip int brief"...

When i'm adding the "local $/" statement, it prints what you expect.
What does it means ? I'm already using "$_" in a upper "if" statement, right before this code.

Comment: Does it mean that the "while (<DATA>) read the file as one line instead of multiple lines ?

Comment: The question has been modified quite a bit… One hypothesis was the that `while (<DATA>)` command would read the file as one line instead of multiple lines. Another is that the file only has one line, despite you thinking otherwise. The code shown isn't using the split name, so why do you care about it at all? If there's a function call inside the loop, then maybe that function is using the `<DATA>` handle and that's causing your loop to finish. Consider using `my` more extensively — `use strict; use warnings;` is good! Use lexical file handles: `open my $fh, '<', $fichier or die`.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Jonathan's answer

Here's a relevant section from [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) that discusses what *could* be happening in your program

> In most cases you want to
>          localize these variables [ like $/ ] before changing them, since if you don't, the
>          change may affect other modules which rely on the default values of the
>          special variables that you have changed. This is one of the correct
>          ways to read the whole file at once:
>
> ```
>        open my $fh, "<", "foo" or die $!;
>        local $/; # enable localized slurp mode
>        my $content = <$fh>;
>        close $fh;
> ```
>
> But the following code is quite bad:
>
> ```
>        open my $fh, "<", "foo" or die $!;
>        undef $/; # enable slurp mode
>        my $content = <$fh>;
>        close $fh;
> ```
>
> since some other module, may want to read data from some file in the
>          default "line mode", so if the code we have just presented has been
>          executed, the global value of $/ is now changed for any other code
>          running inside the same Perl interpreter.

Hope this helps.